# Access JSON Array without array name

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin

I have a JSON object:

```
{
   "login_name":"hello@gmail.com",
   "login_pass":"abc123",
   "created_on":"2021-01-17 19:20:07",
   "user_id":"1",
   "active":"1"
}
```

I don't know how to access it because it doesn't have a name.
This is using Volley:

```
val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    { response ->
        val obj = JSONObject(response.toString()) // this works and outputs the JSON object
        val test: JSONObject = obj.getJSONObject("login_name") // this doesn't work

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    },
    { error ->
        Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
)
```

I also tried converting the Json object to an array but that didn't work either...

Looked at:
[Get JSONArray without array name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797888/get-jsonarray-without-array-name), [How can i write Android Json parsing without array name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328953/how-can-i-write-android-json-parsing-without-array-name)

EDIT:

```
val obj = JSONObject(response)
```

That didn't work for me because:
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
(String!) defined in org.json.JSONObject
((MutableMap<Any?, Any?>..Map<*, *>?)) defined in org.json.JSONObject
(JSONTokener!) defined in org.json.JSONObject

But after 2 days of trying, this worked... Didn't think I could just do that

```
val test = response.getString("login_name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` is indeed a `jsonObject`, you could use it without know its name:

```
String login_name= response.getString("login_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are all most doing it right. Ass i see you convert the object to a string, and thats why you cant access the data afterwards.

```
   val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    { response ->
        val obj = JSONObject(response) // this works and outputs the JSON object
        val test: JSONObject = obj.getJSONObject("login_name") // this doesn't work

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    },
    { error ->
        Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
)
```

Try this, without the toString() function on response.